# О происхождении слова «обло»

Tags: этимология

Уважаемые исследователи русского языка, знаете ли вы что-либо о происхождении слова «обло»? «Обло» - это вид углового соединения брёвен, применяемый при изготовлении сруба, также подобное соединение называется «в чашу», «русский угол».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В словаре Срезневского *обло* (обьло) - сфера, шар. "Свалявъ обло яко камень". *Платъ обьла* - полушарие, свод. *Обельство* - округлость. Из учебника по истории Древней Руси можно вспомнить *обельных холопов*, т.е. полных, "круглых".
Форма полукруглой чаши, которая вырубалась в бревне, дала название строительному термину : *рубить в обло*.

Answer (score 2):

Не заглядывая в словари, смею предположить.
В характеристике русского царизма классиком сказано: Чудище обло, огромно, стоземно и лайяй. Здесь обло ассоциируется  с плотным всеохватыванием , как в облаке. Если в облаке, то весь, до нитки. То же должно быть и в строительстве.

Answer (score 2):

Могу добавить параллель из английского.
В нем есть слово "gobble" - пожирать. Вероятно "goblin" того же происхождения и означает "прожора, пузан, глотатель". Слова "обло" и "облако" кажутся мне весьма сходными. Облако можно отдаленно трактовать как "пузо в небе". А теперь учтем, что английский младше русского в значительной степени. Саксы, одни из носителей праанглийского, пришли, с немалой долей вероятности, из славянских земель. Все, относящееся к основным жизненным потребностям в языках, имеет самое древнее происхождение в большинстве случаев. Так что, английский "gobble" и старорусское "обло" в доисторические времена на русских землях имели единого предка со значением "величина, дородность, округлость".

Comment: Спасибо. Это весьма интересная информация!

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Сыном юриста. Облако все пожирает: и ворон в небе, и вершины гор, и улицы городов. Но облако и обло относятся друг к другу как предмет и его свойство, как синька синяя. Облако материально, а обло нет, как большое , близкое, вкусное. Обло - всеохватывающее, всепроникающее. Английские аналоги - это как бы частный случай облака или обло. Вопрос сыну юриста: а Вы не пытались выяснить этимологию английских слов, что обосабливает их от Облака и обло? И еще, извините, а что означает часть имени "Конан"?

Answer (score 0):

Читаю книгу Гедеонова "Русь и Варяги" (Часть 1, стр.22). В ней он анализирует слово **обелъ**, демонстрируя, что это общеславянское слово, а не скандинавское или германское. Приводит несколько примеров, в том числе и со словом **обло, сферическая форма** в качестве значения болгарского *сфера* (σφαῖρα). Кстати, в болгарском языке слово *обло* действительно означает **круг**. Из других примеров, наиболее интересны:

Obly (чешский) - овальный

Obilny (Моравия) - зажиточные крестьяне

Obiln (Стирия, Краина, Хорутане) - полный

Однако, слова **обло** и **облако** могут и не являться родственниками. Разве что "дальними". Некоторые авторы производят слово **облако** от старославянского гла­го­ла **«обла­ка­ти»** (современное *"облачать"*), что зна­чит *«оде­вать»*, *«окру­жать»*. (https://troniks.ru/word/Kak_pishetsya_oblako)